# How do I create an index on a table that is non unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing, unique-key

I want an index on a non-primary key column, but this column may have nulls in it. I find on a normal unique index, it (rightly so) only allows one null.

Is that possible?

and what is the syntax for this?

Comment: @Mark: the SQL standard says nothing about indexes - only about constraints.  Classically, I believe DB2 first introduced the 'UNIQUE with at most one NULL' interpretation, and most other DBMS followed suit.  It would be handy to be able to do '`CREATE UNIQUE UNLESS NULL INDEX idxname ON table(col1);`'.  Sadly, I know of no system where you can do that.

Comment: @Jonathan: multiple NULLs in a UNIQUE column is allowed in Oracle (10g), no matter if the unique-ness is defined by a constraint or by an index - just tested this to verify.

Comment: @Bob - thanks; that is interesting to know (and is why SO is useful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX idxname ON table(col1);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: yep, i probably should've looked up how the syntax to create an index worked before i posted that question!